# Oracle JDK 1.8 supported on AIX server?

Tags: java-8, aix, oraclejdk

I am new to AIX environment want to check if we can install JDK 8 on AIX server by overriding the IBM JDK.
If yes, how?.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle JDK 1.8 **for AIX** does not exist.
If you really want JDK 1.8, you can override your current (I suppose now you have an older version) downloading a new one from [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/java-sdk/).

Just to be clear, every version of Oracle JDK or JRE is machine dependent. And it is compiled to run only on a defined set of operating systems. You can see the complete list of Oracle's JDK supported OSs [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/).

Looking around I saw there is a [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net) (Open Java Development Kit) porting to PowerPC/AIX, they're are actively working to have a stable 1.8 version.

- [OpenJDK - PowerPC/AIX Port Project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/ppc-aix-port/)
- [OpenJDK Wiki - PowerPC/AIX Port Project](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=13041681)
- [OpenJDK PowerPC Port](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Esimonis/ppc-aix-port/)

Consider that OpenJDK is not only a free and open source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE). But it is also actively supported [by Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) (primarily) and by [IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Harmony).

Comment: Hi freeDev,Thanks for the reply.Cant we use Oracle JDK with AIX?.Is it supported in AIX architecture?.

Comment: If it doesn't exist it stands to reason that you can't use it, and it's not supported.